# MySQL delete record using Join not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to delete the record using `JOIN` but not working so I have tried with `IN` it also not working. But if I change `DELETE` to `SELECT` it working fine.

## Working

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
     WHERE T1.ID IN (
     SELECT T1.ID FROM T1 
     JOIN T2 ON T2.PID = T1.ID WHERE T2.Email LIKE '%mitul%')
```

## Not working

```
DELETE FROM T1 
     WHERE T1.ID IN (
     SELECT T1.ID FROM T1 
     JOIN T2 ON T2.PID = T1.ID WHERE T2.Email LIKE '%mitul%')

DELETE FROM T1 
     JOIN T2 ON T2.PID = T1.ID WHERE T2.Email LIKE '%mitul%'
```

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Read an introduction/manual including grammar re the parts of the language you use before you use them & before you ask a question re how you used them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mention the table name or table alias name after the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE T1
FROM T1 
JOIN T2 ON T2.PID = T1.ID 
WHERE T2.Email LIKE '%mitul%'
```

Please find the demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a12d23a61653ea54b35ff0e399754fc6)

In case if you want to remove the matching entry from the both tables, use `T1, T2` after the `DELETE` statement.

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1 
JOIN T2 ON T2.PID = T1.ID 
WHERE T2.Email LIKE '%mitul%'
```

[**Demo for the same**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0676cfbe5a702ae33ed30a763f83fee)